# Is PHP's session_start() idempotent?

Tags: php, session

What it says above. Unsurprisingly, I couldn't find a clear answer to this.

I just want to know if calling it more than once in a script will cause a problem.

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new word. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

Comment: -1 for using wrong site to teach other people new words. And for not even running a simple test before asking a question/nor reading documentation page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [**the manual**](https://www.php.net/session_start) :

> As of PHP 4.3.3, calling `session_start()` after the session was
> previously started will result in an error of level `E_NOTICE`.
>
> Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.

So, it will not do much -- except raise a notice, which indicates there is some kind of a *problem* ; which means you should not call this function more than once.

**Edit after @hakre's comment :** Just to be sure, I've tested with the following portion of code, which calls session_start() twice, after making sure errors and notices get reported :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

session_start();
session_start();
```

And I do get the following notice :

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /.../temp.php on line 6
```

Comment: The manual is not exactly correct about that behaviour AFAIK. Some bug-reports should be available.

Comment: @hakre : what do you mean by that ? I just tested calling `session_start()` twice, and I do get the notice I was expecting. *(tested on PHP 5.3.6)*

Comment: This differs between PHP versions as well as the return value.

Comment: The manual explains that this notice is raised since PHP 4.3.3 *(and, really, no-one should be using PHP 4 anymore)* ; and that the return value when the session fails to start has changed with PHP 5.3.0 ; have you noticed any other difference between versions of PHP *(if yes, reporting them might be useful, to ensure the manual is updated)* ?

Answer (score 0):

No, `session_start` is not idempotent, it has dependencies in the runtime state of the language.

You can normally call it more than once which could give you some warnings or errors without much of a difference, however, if you change the session state and/or configuration between calls, the function won't behave the same.

As calling the function changes the session state, by a very strict view on idempotent, it's totally not.

Additionally, it's important to note that the outcome of that function in correspondence to `$_SESSION` remains defined by the associated store, session name and session id.

Answer (score 0):

It will cause an error (session already started).

But if you ignore the error, it would be idempotent.

In PHP 5.4, we'll get:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php